# Download large file through java client in HTTP

Tags: java, client-server

Is there any way to download large file (like 1 GB) from without buffering which means what ever streams are coming I could directly write it into a file on local machine. As for the large file memory buffer will be occupied.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to download and save a file from internet using Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/921262/how-to-download-and-save-a-file-from-internet-using-java)

Comment: Possible to use FTP instead of http?